Unable to deploy a Hello World contract
I have created a very simple Hello World using anchor framework, rust, and Solana. But I am unable to deploy it, due to rust's version discrepancy.
Refer the below image

I have tried all types of cargo clean, cargo build and rustc update but nothing helped.
I am requesting help.
TIA

Github repo : https://github.com/postmeback/Solana-Hello-World/tree/master

You'll probably need to upgrade to the latest solana CLI version
solana-install update

I would also suggest using wsl
As to why the rust cargo tools aren't working:
when you compile using the rust compiler rustc, the end result is specified bytecode, most likely x86. see this answer on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43385142/how-is-rust-compiled-to-machine-code
As you've guessed, you can't run x86 code on the SVM and that what the cargo-sbf does in converting the LLVM-IR (low level virtual machine intermediate representation), into SBF
see also https://www.rareskills.io/post/solana-smart-contract-language

I am using WSL as well
